# Java SWT GUI Becomes Unresponsive to Updates During Long Running Background Process

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

**Technologies Used:**
Java 1.6
SWT GUI

**Problem:**
GUI information updates eventually stall (GUI becomes completely unresponsive) after approximately 60 minutes of a background task running.

The problem appears to be with the GUI updates, and I cannot figure out how to remedy this situation (reviewed the Java concurrency options, etc.). The Optimization thread periodically updates the text box in the GUI with processing information. During my testing, this "update" lags SIGNIFICANTLY behind the console output and database output--by that, assume the optimization performs 4000 optimization steps. The console may report working on optimization step 1900 (confirmed in the database) but the GUI stills outputs information from step 700.

**Background Info:**
I am running a machine learning optimization task and incorporate the task into an SWT GUI. The task may take an hour or more to run to completion depending on parameters. I designed the optimization task as a separate thread. The GUI allows the user to press a button to launch the optimization. The GUI includes (to simplify) 1) a table of tasks and 2) a SWT text box for feedback during the optimization. The table of tasks gets updated as each distinct task group is completed. The SWT text box outputs more regular/frequent  feedback (much like `System.out` BUT using threading to update the text box via the GUI EDI thread). That is, I believe I am using at least three threads: 1) the GUI thread, 2) the `aSync` thread for GUI updates (SWT), and 3) a background thread for the optimization itself. *(I mention this because the Java concurrency tutorials expressly direct that long running tasks must run in their own thread to avoid GUI deadlock and starvation. However, even though I think I did this, the GUI still stalls after a long optimization run--and this is what I am trying to fix. Because the optimization runs take so long to complete, the GUI stall is a major issue--losing more than an hour before realizing the GUI stalled.)*

**Basic Program Structure:**
GUI Class-->launches a separate thread for the Optimization Class

Optimization Class can update GUI class components (using SWT `asyncExec`) via call-backs

**Confirmed:**
I can confirm that the background thread runs fully--1) the background thread updates several database tables and all tables are fully and completely updated; 2) `System.out` output directly from the  optimization task sent to  console in Eclipse shows the optimization thread runs fully and completely.

Furthermore, during testing, if I scale back the optimization set to perhaps 400 steps, the GUI seems to run fine.

**Relevant Code:**
GUI CLASS--
Code to Update GUI and in GUI Class (this gets called by the Optimization Class Thread)--

```
public void setFeedback(final String workerthreadinfo, final boolean append) {
try{  
    Display.getDefault().asyncExec(new Runnable(){  
    public void run(){  
        if(!textfeedback.isDisposed() && textfeedback !=null){  
        if (append) {
                      textfeedback.setText(workerthreadinfo + "\n" +
                            textfeedback.getText()) ;
        } else {
            textfeedback.setText(workerthreadinfo) ;
        }  
         } 
    }  
    });
     } .....
```

Instantiation of the Optimization Worker Thread in GUI Class

```
private OptimizerWorkerThread workerthread = 
   new OptimizerWorkerThread(this) ;
```

Code in GUI Class Launching the Optimization Class (as thread)

```
protected void optimize() {
    workerthread.go() ;
}
```

OPTIMIZATION CLASS--
Optimization Thread Method "linking" to the GUI (guiwindow = GUI class above)

```
// ==================================================================
// GUI Update Methods
// ================================================================== 
public void updateFeedBackInfo(String update, boolean append) {
    guiwindow.setFeedback(update, append) ;
}
```

Example of Call Back to GUI from the Optimization Thread

```
//GUI Feedback
this.updateFeedBackInfo("Saving optimization run record to database ... ", 
   APPENDTEXT ) ; // APPENDTEXT = boolean TRUE instructing GUI textbox to append
```

Comment: Maybe it's just not included in the code samples, but where do you actually tell SWT to redraw your components?

Comment: I do not expressly redraw in SWT.

Answer (score 1):

This does not sound so much like a threading issue.

If you would run by accident in the GUI thread, the GUI would be dead right after clicking the button. So I think we can rule that out.

What you describe sounds more like a memory load / performance issue. I strongly recommend connecting Visualvm with your application and look especially for constantly increasing memory consumption. Also using the profiler included in visualvm might hint at stuff that is consuming lots of cpu or memory.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution Addendum:**

During final testing of this application, I more carefully identified the apparent source of the GUI slow down. By GUI slow-down, I mean the difference between copying 2500 files. The slow-down problem required almost 20 minutes to complete the copy. With the fix applied, the exact same files took less than 1 minute to copy.

**The Problem**
The copy is handled through a Worker Thread. The worker thread periodically updates the GUI. The update includes a ProgressBar update and a text box update.

The text box update appears to be the source of the problem. What I wanted was a text box the PREPENDS the status update information--such as "Copying File C:/hello.txt"--rather than append (available in SWT). To create a faux prepend I used (in a separate thread):

```
textfeedback.setText(workerthreadinfo + "\n" + textfeedback.getText()) ;
```

This little piece of code appears to be the slow-down culprit--and probably is easy to see why. On every file copy, the entire text box contents are copied then the new information is prepended to the text box. After copying about 700 files, this starts to bog down (you can see the slow-down visibly) and continues to deteriorate afterwards.

The fix, although I am not happy with it, is to use the SWT TextBox append() method instead.